# jpegoptim: error creating temp file: mkstemps() failed

Tags: jpeg, jpegoptim

`jpegoptim` gives me this error: `error creating temp file: mkstemps() failed`

```
jpegoptim -o *.jpg
image1.jpg 2000x1333 24bit P JFIF  [OK] 442829 --> 451511 bytes (-1.96%), skipped.
image2.jpg 1500x1124 24bit P Exif XMP IPTC ICC JFIF  [OK] 582748 --> 583528 bytes (-0.13%), skipped.
image3.jpg 2000x1501 24bit P Exif XMP IPTC ICC JFIF  [OK] 630262 --> 634146 bytes (-0.62%), skipped.
image4.jpg 1620x846 24bit P JFIF  [OK] 316664 --> 319702 bytes (-0.96%), skipped.
image5.jpg 1280x855 24bit N Exif XMP Adobe  [OK] 66306 --> 66279 bytes (0.04%), optimized.
jpegoptim: error creating temp file: mkstemps() failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured out the issue yet, it's likely that you don't have write permissions to the directory the image is in.